# Node.js 16 for microsoft/variable-substitution@v1

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, devops, cicd

I'm using `microsoft/variable-substitution@v1` for a long time. Now I'm facing a warning as this is Node.js 12 and recommended to use Node.js 16 as it is deprecated. I updated the `v1` to `v2` but is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [microsoft/variable-substitution](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution) action has been deprecated and archived.

According to its [deprecation notice](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution#deprecation-notice):

> This Action is deprecated. The action keeps working even after archiving this repo. So existing workflows are not impacted and new workflows also work fine. **Any further enhancement or support is not planned for this action.**

One alternative could be to fork it, update its NodeJS version, and start to use that fork.

Another alternative could be to switch to other alternative actions.

I recently wrote this [substitute-action](https://github.com/iamazeem/substitute-action) in Bash/shell to avoid such issues. You might want to check it out as an alternative too.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I went over your repo; unfortunately, I'm only permitted to utilize organization level repo's; but, there is an option for me to request that the org fork your repo; let's see how that goes.